# Files won't load if in root directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a weird problem with my file structure. For some reason, after creating the server and running it, I can't get the index.html to run unless it is in a folder. The browser just shows "Cannot GET /". The same can be said for my JS files that are being used in the index.html. Unless they are in folders and not in the root directory itself, they will not load into index.html. Is this normal or is this because of how I have my server.js file set up?

Here's the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './views')));

app.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log("Listening on Port 8000");
})
```

The folder/file structure is:

```
Root Directory
    - node_modules
    - views
        -js
            -script.js
        - pages
            -about.html
            -contact.html
            -home.html
        - index.html
    - server.js
```

The problem is when the file structure is:

```
Root Directory
    - node_modules
    - pages
        -about.html
        -contact.html
        -home.html
    - index.html
    - script.js
    - server.js
```

The express.static is also pointing to pages instead of views.

Any suggestions on why this is the case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

simply, `express.static(path.join(__dirname, './views'))` will serve all files in folder `views`
if you go to `/pages/index.html` . this will check folder `view` for `/page/index.html` if exist `index.html`, it will serve you this file else it will check if you have any handle route logic
You can set multi serve-static.